# What kind of logic is in "Logic in the Theory and Practice of Lawmaking"?

Tags: logic

I was browsing the Legal Reasoning section at a law library, and stumbled on  2016 Springer book [*Logic in the Theory and Practice of Lawmaking*](https://www.amazon.ca/Theory-Practice-Lawmaking-Michal-Araszkiewicz/dp/3319371460). I was curious and flipped. OMG! I have J.D. from  Canadian law school and LL.M, and I never saw these math-looking symbols before!

[image]

1. What kind of logic is this? 
   I scanned just the pages with the most logic symbols.
2. What level and subject in university do you learn this logic?!?  Google previews the book, and [page xix](https://books.google.com/books?id=qAC0CgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Logic+in+the+Theory+and+Practice+of+Lawmaking&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjukLb9mo7jAhUQCs0KHbKBAPIQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=Logic%20in%20the%20Theory%20and%20Practice%20of%20Lawmaking&f=false) starts to list contributors' degrees. I don't see any math degree.
3. If Canada's law schools are so great, why don't they teach this logic? Anybody know if Ivy League/Stanford or Oxbridge law schools teach it?   "[Canadian law schools have notoriously high admission standards and successful applicants are justifiably proud of their accomplishment.](https://www.futureproject.ca/barriers-entry-law-school-uk-less-difficult-canada/)" "[Canadian law schools are considered difficult to get into since there's on average, higher admissions standards.](https://lawstudents.ca/forums/topic/34749-future-law-plans-uk-law-school-right-from-high-school/?do=findComment&comment=418268)"

[Steven Haddock](https://www.quora.com/profile/Steven-Haddock) LL.B. Osgoode

> [Canada. luckily, just has “first-tier” law schools where almost all the students pass and go on to get licensed as lawyers.](https://www.quora.com/How-does-the-cost-of-law-school-in-Canada-compare-to-the-cost-in-the-United-States/answer/Steven-Haddock)

Comment: In (3) you seem to be curiously fast to assume as fact that law schools _ought to_ have taught you this formalism. From your excerpt it seems much more likely that it is something novel that the author(s) _propose that it would be useful to adopt_ as a reasoning tool. They may or may not be _right_ about it being useful. One would need to study the paper in detail (_and_, I suppose, have some firsthand experience with practicing law) before one can form an informed opinion about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If I were to guess, it's a form of Modal Logic called *"Deontic Logic"*. There's a quite extensive page on the [Stanford encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-deontic/).

   If you want a proper introduction, I would start with learning at least some Propositional Logic, First-order Logic, and then some Modal Logic.
2. I've taught such a course as two separate half semester courses (one for Propositional / First-order, the other for Modal logic) to 2nd year bachelor students of artificial intelligence, so it's not as scary and mathematical as it might seem.

   Modal logic is not as much used in mathematics as in other fields of logical research, such as philosophy and cognitive science, so researches in modal logic don't necessarily have a degree in mathematics.
3. Perhaps that is a question best asked to Canadian law school professors, instead of to mathematicians.

Comment: thank you!!!!!!